# Returning value to codeigniter view

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I need help about view in codeigniter. Usually i just do the same way and it is work. Right now i got confused or maybe i am wrong.

Here's the controller:

```
        ...

        $curl_exec = curl_exec($ch);
        $result = json_decode($curl_exec, TRUE);
        $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        if($httpcode == 200)
        {
            $msg['success'] = 'Succcessfully completed step 1!';
            $this->load->view('back/vproductadd', $msg);
        } elseif ($httpcode == 500) {
            $msg['double'] = 'Succcessfully completed step 1!';
            $this->load->view('back/vproductadd', $msg);
        } {
            $msg['others'] = 'Succcessfully completed step 1!';
            $this->load->view('back/vproductadd', $msg);
        }
```

And this is the view:

```
                <?php
                    if (isset($success)) {
                        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible'>";
                        echo "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>";
                        echo "<h4><i class='icon fa fa-ban'></i> Alert!</h4>";
                        echo "$success";
                        echo "</div>" ;
                    }
                  ?>
                  <?php
                    if (isset($double)) {
                        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible'>";
                        echo "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>";
                        echo "<h4><i class='icon fa fa-ban'></i> Alert!</h4>";
                        echo "$double";
                        echo "</div>" ;
                    }
                  ?>
                  <?php
                    if (isset($others)) {
                        echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible'>";
                        echo "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>";
                        echo "<h4><i class='icon fa fa-ban'></i> Alert!</h4>";
                        echo "$others";
                        echo "</div>" ;
                    }
                  ?>

                  // Form
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Product Code</label>
                    <input type="text" name="codeproduct" id="codeproduct" class="form-control"  placeholder="Product Code">
                  </div>
                 // ...
                 // End Form
```

[image: Screenshot]

The message should show on the alert box,but it wont show. if i add `exit();` at the end of condition message show. is there any something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

you need to put 'else' on the last stametement.

```
if($httpcode == 200)
    {
        $msg['success'] = 'Succcessfully completed step 1!';
        $this->load->view('back/vproductadd', $msg);
    } elseif ($httpcode == 500) {
        $msg['double'] = 'Succcessfully completed step 1!';
        $this->load->view('back/vproductadd', $msg);
    } else {
        $msg['others'] = 'Succcessfully completed step 1!';
        $this->load->view('back/vproductadd', $msg);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is - if you let your script in a controller die, CI isn't done yet.
Because it loads @first all views in order to put them finally out.

The application flow chart below should show, how it works.
[image]

> For more information, take a look [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/appflow.html)